# Pegar hora e avisar ao usuário

Tags: java, android

Criei esse código no Android Studio pra informar as horas dos ônibus daqui da minha cidade mas queria que o app informasse qual o próximo ônibus a pessoa poderia pegar assim que ela acessasse a list view e não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso.

Segue o código da list view:

```
public class Roncoroni extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<TemOnibusTeste> adicionarOnibus() {

        ArrayList<TemOnibusTeste> onibusTestes = new ArrayList<TemOnibusTeste>();
        TemOnibusTeste e = new TemOnibusTeste("Segunda a sexta", "");
        onibusTestes.add(e);

        e = new TemOnibusTeste("Bairro          Centro", "");
        onibusTestes.add(e);

        e = new TemOnibusTeste("05:50             N/A*", "");
        onibusTestes.add(e);

        e = new TemOnibusTeste("N/A* = Não fica parado no Centro. Chega e sai.", "");
        onibusTestes.add(e);

        return onibusTestes;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.petroita_roncoroni);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new TemOnibusAdapter(this, adicionarOnibus());
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Seria mais ou menos desse jeito:

[image: Não como grid view mas como list view]

Esse é um print do meu app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe TemOnibusTeste:

```
public class TemOnibusTeste {

    private String nome;
    private String via;

    public TemOnibusTeste(String nome, String via) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.via = via;

    }

    public TemOnibusTeste(String s) {
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getVia() {
        return via;
    }

    public void setVia(String via) {
        this.via = via;

    }
}
```

Comment: Inclua também a classe `TemOnibusTeste`, para que saibamos o que está a ser guardado para cada ônibus

Comment: Atualizei o post Isac. Espero que possa me ajudar.

Comment: Mas se a sua classe dos onibus não tem qualquer informação de datas e horas não tem como saber se está algum a partir ou não

Comment: Por isso estou em dúvida! Não sei nem ao menos por onde começar!

Comment: Bem os primeiros passos seriam mesmo incluir a informação de data e hora dentro de cada onibus. Pode faze-lo utilizando o formato `Date` por exemplo. Depois teria que alterar o `Adapter` apropriadamente para mostrar essa informação, assim como inseri-la quando cria onibus. Depois para saber se está algum para partir terá que consultar a informação dos onibus, o que seria mais apropriado se a mesma tivesse guardada algures, quer seja em SqLite ou em firebase, caso contrário não conseguira persistir a mesma entre as várias activities

Comment: Mesmo querendo fazer tudo em memoria como está na pergunta teria que percorrer os vários onibus com um laço e calcular a distância da data corrente a cada um dos que tem na lista e guardar apenas aqueles que estão a menos de X minutos. Como vê ainda tem muito caminho pela frente!

Comment: Nossa Isac! Muito obrigado mesmo! Vou tentar fazer do jeito que me diz!